# Why do my Moment Component in React not able to display the correct time when using "ago" property?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a small React app and I want to format the UTC time to be displayed as relative time using ago property in `<Moment />` component.

The initial time that I am deriving from my state is the time as: `"2023-12-02T21:00:05.696Z"`. I am converting it to UTC:

```
const lastUpdatedOnTime = moment.utc(new Date("2023-12-02T21:00:05.696Z"));
```

I am passing the `lastUpdateTime`  to `<Moment>` component:

```
<Moment interval="1000" ago format="DD/MM hh:mm">
        {lastUpdatedOnTime}
</Moment>
```

and the output is 02/12 09:30 and not the relative time I am expecting, e.g. 30min ago.

Have tried different properties, also searched on the net.

Answer (score 0):

use fromNow

```
import React  from 'react';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Moment fromNow>1976-04-19T12:59-0500</Moment>
        );
    }
}
```

Outputs:
`<time>40 years ago</time>`

Comment: I have already tried it does not seems to change nothing.